# How to use the category page layout update to insert a cms block in the category.products block?

Tags: blocks, cms

I am trying to add a CMS block in-between the Category page description and the products list for a single category page. I believe I would need to use the Custom Layout Update to add the CMS block. If I reference the Content block, I can get the cms block to display at the top of the content with this:

```
<reference name="content">
 <block type="cms/block" name="cutlery_page_addition" before="product_list">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cutlery_page_addition</block_id></action>
 </block>
</reference>
```

But how would I target a child block of the content block? I tried this with no luck:

```
<reference name="category.products">
 <block type="cms/block" name="cutlery_page_addition" before="product_list">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cutlery_page_addition</block_id></action>
 </block>
</reference>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just call this block at catalog/category/view.phtml between

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

and

```
<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
```

using the code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cutlery_page_addition');?>
```

But magento is provide  add an cms  static block from admin at Category.Just select any category..... `Design Setting>Display Mode>` select `Static block and products`

Comment: Thanks for this feedback Amit! Your last suggestion worked for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to edit phtml add output attribute to the block tag

```
<reference name="category.products">
     <block type="cms/block" name="cutlery_page_addition" before="product_list" output="toHtml">
          <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cutlery_page_addition</block_id></action>
     </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Hey @balajisoundar I just tried this and the block just rendered after the footer on my site.

Comment: @Legendary_Fish try this:
`<reference name="content">
     <block type="cms/block" name="myname" after="category.products">
          <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_name</block_id></action>
     </block>
</reference>`

Answer (score 0):

content, left. right are all types of `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List` and therefore automatically rendered.

*catalog.products* extends `Mage_Core_Block_Template` which doesn't have this auto render feature.
You have to put your `echo $this->getChildHtml('cutlery_page_addition');` manually where you want to have it in the belonging `.phtml` file.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen! I was starting to gather this was the case. I just needed it spelled out somewhere.